# Manga where the main character is held captive in some facility and experimented on

Tags: story-identification, manga

**Where did you read it?** 
Online, I don't remember the site. 
**Art Style?**  
Japanese Manga 
**Manga & Anime?** 
I don't know for sure but I don't think it has a anime adaption, there shouldn't be enough chapters. 
**Characters** 
MC was probably an early Adult. I think one of his friends was a Labia that died later.
**Fantasy creatures?**
There were demi-humans, I can't remember the monsters. 
**Target Audience?**
Probably Seinen, there were some more graphic scenes. 
**Genre?** 
I assume Fantasy, Seinen, Action

In the beginning he was held captive in some facility and experimented on.
He had to fight there on a regular basis until he escaped.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this question by looking at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question), then [edit]ing it to include any further details that come to mind. The more info you can provide, the better the chances that someone will be able to ID this for you. In particular, it'd be helpful to know whether this was in full colour or mostly black & white.

Comment: Do you recall how he got into this facility? Kidnapped? Reincarnated and found himself there? Born there normally? Any details on the experiments? Were they just measuring things or torturing him, or did it involve graphic body modification? Or infusing with superpowers? Did he escape in the first chapter, or much later on? Or did he not escape at all and that was just a goal? Do you remember what year you read this, and about how many total chapters there were?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think the Manga starts with him already being in the facility. I'm not sure if he was also born there. He has to endure a lot in there but the aim is to experiment on him and make him stonger. I don't remember graphic body modifications but in his world he would probably be considered a superhuman but there a still stronger ones. He escapes very early probably in a span of 1-3 chapters. I probably read it about 1-2 years ago. I think there where about 20-30 chapters.

Comment: I don't think this is it, but there's a few similarities to The Kingdoms of Ruin/Hametsu no Oukoku. Protagonist is a witch's apprentice, escapes from a facility in the 2nd chapter. There were 20 chapters a year ago. I don't think it has demihumans, though. Can you rule that out?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that's not it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[Kuro no Maou](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/kuro-no-maou)*.

> Kurono Maou is a high school student who is sensitive of his sharp eyes and bad expression. No girlfriend but gifted with friends in his own way, he had been living a peaceful life. But one day, without any reason, Kurono was attacked by a mysterious headache while in the literature clubroom and fainted. When he finally awoke.......Swords & magic, filled with monsters, an orthodox different world summoning.

The protagonist is a high school student summoned to another world, where he is kept captive via a crown that causes him pain if he disobeys. He's forced to fight, initially against "dolls" and then against humans, and is made stronger. He escapes in the second chapter, running away from a fight against a princess-like woman.

He encounters and befriends a fairy; he moves to a nearby village where he becomes an adventurer, and befriends several demi-humans, including a lamia:

[image: Adventurer friends]

They die in the 9th chapter via a fight with religious purists, led by the woman from the second chapter.

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tag `Human Experiment/s`, filtered to Seinen and Fantasy.

Comment: Thank's a lot  that is the one :D

Comment: @saris You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).